# Can products have multiple prices (regular/student etc.)?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine

For our project we need products to have multiple prices.
All of these prices need to be editable in the backend and they need to be selectable for the customer.
This must not be done with vouchers.
As far as I can see you can only set a regular price and bulk prices.

Answer (score 1):

what about using variants to differentiate products among the types.

You could use a custom drop down field to select the type of variant like "Student" "Regular" "Senior" and more. For each variant you could then set a specific price or link a price card. In frontend a user can then switch between all the variants and gets the variant specific price.

If you have further differentiation types, like color, size, boxing type etc., you can also combine these to create more variants.

But this approach would mean, that in worst case the number of variants might grow very fast.

Comment: I had the same idea with the same concerns. Moreoever this would lead to more product ids, but I guess this would not be a blocker.

Comment: Exactly. From what I know from XC there is no other OOTB way of easyly achive this.